# Question about Runge Theorem (Stein's Complex Analysis)

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

[image]

I don't understand why we can extend continuity here. I read something that union of all $Q_i, i = \overline{1,n}$ is a dense set of $Q$ but I still don't understand.